# UPDATE campo BIGINT[] a partir de um SELECT

Tags: array, postgresql

Tenho realizar um update em um campo

`permissao_ver`

Sendo o mesmo o tipo `bigint[]`, resposta do campo : `'{1,2,3,4,5,11,44,56,75,11}'`

Minha Query

```
UPDATE callcenter.pausa  
SET permissao_ver = '{"(SELECT cod_grupo FROM crm.usuariosgrupos
                        WHERE habilitar = 1)"}'::bigint[] 
WHERE habilitado = 1 AND permissao_ver is null
```

Preciso pegar os codigos que o select vai me retornar de dar um update nesse campo `bigint[]` `'{XX,XX,XX,X,XX,X}'`

Comment: O campo cod_grupo já é um array (bigint[])? No update você quer simplesmente substituir um array pelo outro ou unir o valor existente com o resultado do subselect?

Answer (score 1):

Resolvido .

```
UPDATE callcenter.pausa  
SET permissao_ver = array(SELECT cod_grupo 
                          FROM crm.usuariosgrupos
                          WHERE habilitar = 1)
WHERE habilitado = 1 
AND permissao_ver is null
```